# This second option is not printing the binary. The goal is to get input as a decimal number and output a binary

Tags: python

This second option is not printing the binary. The goal is to get input as a decimal number and output a binary.
This is  a section of the code:

```
if the_option == 2:
  decimal_string = input("DECIMAL-STR> ")
  decimal = float(decimal_string)
  binary_string = ""

  while decimal > 0 and isinstance(decimal, int):
   decimal = decimal / 2
   remainder = decimal % 2
   math.trunc(remainder)
   binary_string = binary_string + str(remainder)
print("Decimal " + decimal_string + " is Binary " + binary_string)
```

Comment: In your code you set the type of the decimal variable to float, so when you check if it is an int in your while loop the code will always fail.

Comment: You can also use `bin()` to get the binary value of the decimal or if you only want to print binary value of decimal then you can format it in print string as follows `f"{10:b}"` it will print `1010`.

Comment: After solving `float` and `int` error you will encounter error in print statement because you cannot concatenate `decimal_string` (int) with string. So you can use f-strings or convert `decimal_string` to int or else use `,` and not `+`.

Comment: n Line 4: Move  binary_string = "" at the  bottom

Answer (score 0):

I found 4 mistakes.

1. you have to use `int()` instead of `float()
2. you can use `//` instead of `/` to get integer result
3. you have to calculate `reminder` on original `decimal` - so you have to do it before you calculate new `decimal`
4. you have to put binary digits in reverse order `str(remainder) + binary_string` instead of `binary_string + str(remainder)`

```
#decimal_string = input("DECIMAL-STR> ")

for decimal_string in ['16', '7', '128']:
    decimal = int(decimal_string)  # use `int()` instead of `float()`
    binary_string = ""
    
    while decimal > 0:
       remainder = decimal % 2  # calculate on original `decimal`
       decimal = decimal // 2   # use `//` to get integer 
       binary_string = str(remainder) + binary_string  # reverse order
    
    print("Decimal " + decimal_string + " is Binary " + binary_string)
```

Result:

```
Decimal 16 is Binary 10000
Decimal 7 is Binary 111
Decimal 128 is Binary 10000000
```